# How to update a child association only if a potential parent object is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Assume we have a parent model

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
end
```

We have already created a `child` object (persisted in database).

We then create a **potential** `parent = Parent.new` object for the `child`. Potential means that this parent may not ever be saved to the database and nothing should be changed in this case. Is it possible to set the child for the `parent` in a such a way that the `child` is updated (i.e. its foreign key is set) only after we call `parent.save`?

Of course this can be accomplished with hooks but I just wonder if there was an Rails inbuilt way to do this.

#### What does not work

`parent.child = child` will automatically save the parent so that's not an option, because we may not want to save the parent at all.

`parent.build_child(child.attributes)` will not work, because the `child` is already persisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#app/models/child.rb
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

#app/controllers/parents_controller.rb #-> this can be any controller
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @child = Child.find params[:id]

    @parent = @child.parent.new parent_params
    @parent.save
  end

  private

  def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:x, :y, :z)
  end
end
```

You have to remember that `ActiveRecord` is an "[`ORM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)", which means that it deals with your objects in memory, irrespective of how the database will store them.

You will not be able to populate a "foreign key" which isn't saved. In your case, `child` will not have its `parent_id` foreign key populated until `parent` is saved; however, ActiveRecord will basically pre-populate the various attributes depending on how you invoke the objects.

---

The above builds a new `parent` off an existing `child`.

Because you're defining the `foreign_key` in the `child` model, it will only be populated on save.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that indeed works. However I encountered this problem in a situation where the `parent` actually has two different types of children, say `child_type1` and `child_type2`, both already persisted. I wonder if there would be an alternative way so that both could be updated in the case when the parent is saved.

Comment: Are the types maintained through an `STI` (Single Table Inheritance)?

Comment: And can you give me context as to what you mean by "both updated" - how would you know if both are associated to a parent if the parent does not yet exist?

Comment: Yes both are STI. What I would like is that I could have the effect of `parent.child_type1 = child_type1` and `parent.child_type2 = child_type2` if I decide at a later stage save the parent. So e.g. I will display the `parent` to a user, which then can persist it if so chooses. If he chooses, all the associations would be already wired so that I would only need to call `parent.save`.

Comment: So basically in every request I'm forming a proposal `parent` object based on decisions made by the user so far. This is displayed to the user but not persisted unless the user decides to do so.

Comment: Hmm. From what you've written, I would recommend against an STI -- it's meant for calling the various models/classes explicitly (`ChildType1.find` etc). You'd probably better with an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) in your child model, allowing you to invoke as many `child` records as you wish, declaring the `type` in ActiveRecord

Comment: If you write another question, I'll provide an answer with my recommendations if you want. What you're asking is out of the scope of the original post